# Angular firebase creating childs in database

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I have uploaded business information to database (`createItemAuth()`) and I am trying to upload trucks and trailers as a child in database to company, but that doesnt work. Thats my try :

```
export interface Trucks {
  name: string;
}

export interface Trailers {
  name: string;
}


export interface Data {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  address2: string;
  pscode: string;
  ccode: string;
  name2: string;
  trucks: Trucks;
  trailers: Trailers;
}
export class BackService {
  constructor(private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,     private afAuth: AngularFireAuth ) {
    this.busCollection = this.afDatabase.list(`imones`);
  }
  busines = {} as Data;
  createItemAuth() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      this.afDatabase.object(`${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}/company/`).update(this.busines)
        });
    }

createTruckAuth() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      this.afDatabase.list(`${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}/company/trucks/`).push(this.busines.trucks)
    });
  }
  createTrailAuth() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      this.afDatabase.list(`${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}/comapny/trails/`).push(this.busines.trailers)
    });
  }
```

**HTML OF CREATING:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="back.busines.name" type="text">
      <input [(ngModel)]="back.busines.address" type="text">
      <input [(ngModel)]="back.busines.address2" type="text">
      <input [(ngModel)]="back.busines.trucks.name" type="text">
      <input [(ngModel)]="back.busines.trailers.name" type="text">
      <button (click)="back.createTruckAuth();back.createTrailAuth();back.createItemAuth();back.createItem()">create truck</button>
<p *ngFor="let car of carsData" status="success" class="col-sm-4">{{car.name}}></p>
```

**How to create childs in database so I could post info ?**

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: on ngModel back.busines.truck.name - error, cant find name

Comment: What is `back`?